# Долгое подключение к БД

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle-ucp

Есть такой код

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
PoolDataSource pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
System.out.println("getPoolDataSource: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
pds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oraclewin:1521/MyDB");
pds.setUser("user");
pds.setPassword("pass");
pds.setInitialPoolSize(0);
System.out.println("Init DataSource: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Connection con1 = pds.getConnection();
System.out.println("getConnection1: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Connection con2 = pds.getConnection();
System.out.println("getConnection2: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

И он выдает такие времена

```
getPoolDataSource: 451
Init DataSource: 17
getConnection1: 3008
getConnection2: 123
```

Вопрос: почему `getPoolDataSource` и установка первого соединения такие медленные? Это нормально или можно что-то подкрутить?

Причем, если идти в отладчике по шагам, то время выполнения этих двух операций возрастает в разы

```
getPoolDataSource: 2370
getConnection1: 26795
getConnection2: 10979
```

Но это, как я понимаю, из-за общения с отладчиком. Но операции сами по себе изначально долгие. Что там происходит?

База на соседнем компьютере в локальной сети

Comment: Как я понимаю по URL БД не локальная, следовательно скорость может быть любая, для того pool и создается, чтоб минимизировать затраты на подключение.

Comment: @ezhov_da База на соседнем компьютере в локальной сети

Comment: Тогда, думаю, это специфика БД. У нас в локальной сети тоже подключение к БД до 20 сек достигается иногда .

Comment: @ezhov_da Что за специфика? Как ее подправить? Второе подключение 100 миллисекунд. Мне кажется, что истоки все таки в UCP